# Sketch curve $r(t)=\cos t\hat{\bf i}+\sin t\hat{\bf j}+t\hat{\bf k}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

This is from "Multivariable Calculus, Concepts and Contexts" by Stewart.

He says "The parametric equations for this curve are: $x=\cos t$, $y=\sin t$, $z=t$. This makes sense.

However, he then goes on to state that "Since $x^2+y^2=\cos^2t+\sin^2t=1$, the curve must lie on the circular cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$.

I understand the trigonometric identity, I just don't understand how we get to even consider $x^2+y^2=1$ since the vector function is defined as $r(t)=\cos t\hat{\bf i}+\sin t\hat{\bf j}+t\hat{\bf k}$.

Where does $x^2+y^2=1$ come from? How do we get to use that fact when $x=\cos t$ and $y=\sin t$?

Comment: [Take a peek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix) :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple substitution.
You know from trigonometry that $$\cos^2t+\sin^2t=1,$$ and you know from the parametric equation of the curve that $$x=\cos t, y=\sin t.$$
So for any point of the curve, it is true that 
$$x^2+y^2=1.$$
Just notice that you dropped the equality $$z=t,$$
meaning that you get more $(x,y,z)$ values that satisfy the equalities: you obtain a superset of the curve points.
Indeed, the parametric equation corresponds to a linear entity (1D), while $x^2+y^2=1$ defines a surface (2D), which contains the curve.

COMPLEMENT

If you replace $z=t$ by $t=0$, which amounts to projecting the curve on the $xy$ plane, you get a circle centered at the origin, with radius $1$. Coming back to $z=t$, you will "unroll" the circle and extend it in the $z$ direction, while remaining on the cylinder, forming a spring (called an helix in geometry).

Comment: Thank you, I guess the part that is still unclear to me is the transition "So for any point on the curve, it is true that $x^2 + y^2 = 1$".
Why is that the case?

Comment: Even the addition part of $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ doesn't make sense to me, how do we get to do that? Nothing in the parametric equation mentions addition.

Comment: It is a little hard to understand what you don't understand. The two first equations imply the third, that's rather obvious, isn't it ? The addition comes from the trigonometric identity, which is "universal" (independent of any curve). Like you could guarantee that $-1\le x\le1$ because that's a property of the cosine.

Comment: Take an example: $t=\pi/4$. Then $(x,y,z)=(1/\sqrt2,1/\sqrt2,\pi/4)$. Isn't it true that $x^2+y^2=1$ ??

Comment: I understand that part, what I don't understand is "why" we get to use the Trig identity. (sorry, entered early, continuing now in another comment)

Comment: The goal is to understand the shape of the curve, which may not be obvious at first glance. It is a clever observation to establish $x^2+y^2=1$ from the trigonometric identity because it tells you more about the curve: it is inscribed in a cylinder. It you look at it from the "top", you'll see a circle.

Comment: For ex, $x * y = (1/\sqrt{2})^2$, yet we don't use that fact. I guess my confusion comes form the idea that x and y are coordinate points, why do we get to consider and use what they add up to, or multiply to?
The function definition just tells us that $x = cos(t)$ and $y = sin(t)$, why are we allowed to add them up? Does that make any sense?

Comment: Your example is not right. For this curve, $xy=\cos t\sin t$, which tells you about nothing. And similarly, $x+y=\cos t+\sin t$, which doesn't tell you more. $x^2+y^2=1$ is much more interesting as you eliminated the parameter $t$.

Comment: Ok, I got it finally...I was completely overthinking this; thanks a lot for your patience and explanations, I really appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

For parametrizing the cylindre you can parametrize a circle $(\cos(t),\sin(t),0)$ and then "move" along the axe passing through its center $(0,0,0)$ and orthogonal to the plane where the circle is contained (i.e. $(0,0,s)$). Thus the cylinder can be parametrized by $$c(s,t) = (\cos(t),\sin(t),s), \quad t,s \in \mathbb{R}$$ the curve you are considering is $$\gamma(t) = c(t,t),\quad t \in \mathbb{R}$$ and therefore must lie on the cylindre.
The expression $\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)=1$, shows you that a point $(\cos(t),\sin(t),t)$ on your curve is always at a distance $1$ from the point $(0,0,t)$ (the axis of the cylindre).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the graph, very helpful to see what's going on.